NextJS 13 images not displaying from certain components after implementing middleware
I recently implemented middleware in my Next.js 13 application. However, after implementing the middleware, the image component stopped displaying images. I added an exclusion pattern:
"/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|sign-in|sign-up|forgot-password|company-details|forgotPasswordCode|verify-code|update-password).*)",
to the matcher, but the image component still doesn't display images.
Here's my middleware.js:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

export async function middleware(request) {
  const token = await getToken({ req: request, secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET });

  if (!token) return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/sign-in", request.url));

  switch (token.role) {
    case "Administrator":
      break;

    case "Store_Manager":
      // Add the paths that the nurse can access here
      if (!request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/Dashboard")) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/Dashboard/unauthorized", request.url));
      }
      break;

    case "Sales_Department":
      if (!request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/Dashboard/Sales")) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/Dashboard/unauthorized", request.url));
      }
      break;

    case "Inventory_Manager":
      // Add the paths that the pathologist can access here
      if (
        !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/Dashboard/Order") &&
        !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/ui-components/manageorder") &&
        !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/ui-components/viewinventory")
      ) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/ui-components/noAccess", request.url));
      }
      break;

    case "Kitchen_Manager":
      // Add the paths that the pathologist can access here
      if (
        !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/Dashboard/Order") &&
        !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/ui-components/manageorder") &&
        !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/ui-components/viewinventory")
      ) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/Dashboard/unauthorized", request.url));
      }
      break;
    case "Finance_Department":
      // Add the paths that the pathologist can access here
      if (
        !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/Dashboard/Finance") &&
        !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(
          "/Dashboard/TransactionAndPayments"
        ) &&
        !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/Dashboard/Sales")
      ) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/Dashboard/unauthorized", request.url));
      }
      break;

    case "Marketing_Department":
      // Add the paths that the pathologist can access here
      if (!request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/Dashboard/Marketing")) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/Dashboard/unauthorized", request.url));
      }
      break;

    default:
      return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/sign-in", request.url));
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Match all routes except the ones that start with /sign-in, /sign-up, api, and the static folder
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|sign-in|sign-up|forgot-password|company-details|forgotPasswordCode|verify-code|update-password).*)",
  ],
  
};

And this is the structure of my project:
The components that are not displaying images are FooterIllustrationV1.tsx, FooterIllustrationV2.tsx, and FooterIllustrations.tsx.
-prisma
-public
-src
--app
---(auth)
----sign-in/route.ts
----sign-up/route/ts
---(DashboardLayout)
----api
----components
----context
----Dashboard
----db
----demo
----hooks
----icons
----layout
----Models
----styles
----theme
----ui-components
----view
-----account-settings
-----pages
-----auth
------FootIllustrationV1.tsx
------FootIllustrationV2.tsx
-----misc
------FootIllustrations.tsx
----layout.tsx
----loading.tsx
----page.tsx
---@core
---favicon.ico
---global.css
---layout.tsx
---loading.tsx
---providers.tsx
----context
-----settingContext.tsx
--lib
--types
--utils
--middleware.js

Here's my FootIllustrationV1.tsx:
"use client"
// ** React Imports
import { Fragment, ReactNode } from 'react'

// ** MUI Components
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery'
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'

interface FooterIllustrationsProp {
  image1?: ReactNode
  image2?: ReactNode
}

// Styled Components
const MaskImg = styled('img')(() => ({
  bottom: 0,
  zIndex: -1,
  width: '100%',
  position: 'absolute'
}))

const Tree1Img = styled('img')(() => ({
  left: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  position: 'absolute'
}))

const Tree2Img = styled('img')(() => ({
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  position: 'absolute'

}))

const FooterIllustrationsV1 = (props: FooterIllustrationsProp) => {
  // ** Props
  const { image1 } = props

  // ** Hook
  const theme = useTheme()

  // ** Vars
  const hidden = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'))

  if (!hidden) {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {image1 || <Tree1Img alt='tree' src='/images/pages/auth-v1-tree.png' />}
        <MaskImg alt='mask' src={`/images/pages/auth-v1-mask-${theme.palette.mode}.png`} />
       
      </Fragment>
    )
  } else {
    return null
  }
}

export default FooterIllustrationsV1

sign-in page example for image not loading:-

